# passing File name programmatically for log4j.property file

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

In my current Java application.. I should create separate log files with the different string received from multiple threads and corresponding messages should go to that particular log file.. Is there any way to change the log file name in log4j.properties dynamically without doing in a programmatic way.I tried setting

```
    System.setProperty("logFile.name", str);
```

but once SystemProperty is set the class loader wont change each and every time. Is there any way to of setting it many time or any other way ?

Comment: Wouldn't logging the `thread name and other thread specific` data for each thread when logging to logger be better?

Comment: ya it will do good. But I should create seperate log file based on information received from threads.